# Regex - negative lookbehind for any character excluding pure whitespace

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

I'm trying to write a regex pattern that will fail a match if the preceding pattern contains any character except pure whitespace, for example

```
--hello (match)
--goodbye (match)
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) --date (fail)
  --comment with some indentation (match)
    --another comment with some indentation (match)
```

The closest I've got to is with this pattern I made `(?<!.)--.*\n`, that gives me this result

```
--hello (match)
--goodbye (match)
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) --date (fail)
  --comment with some indentation (fail)
    --another comment with some indentation (fail)
```

I've tried `(?<!\s)--.*\n` and `(?<=\S)--.*\n` but both return no matches at all

EDIT: a regexr.com illustrating the issue more clearly [regexr.com/6j0mt](https://regexr.com/6j0mt)

Comment: Try `(?<=^[^\S\r\n]*)--.*` or `^\h*\K--.*`. Or just use `^[^\S\r\n]*(--.*)` and get Group 1 value.

Comment: If you are just trying to validate each line then use: `^[ \t]*--`

Comment: Neither of these patterns do the trick

Comment: Check this: https://regexr.com/6j0nc

Comment: https://regexr.com/6j0nf and https://regexr.com/6j0ni - both my top suggestions work (JS tested in Chrome).

Comment: Ahhh I see you changed the flags to include multiline `/gm`, I had mine just at global `/g` and hence didn't work

Comment: Yes we need to use `m` (MULTILINE) since we are using anchor `^`

Comment: So, what works for you?

Comment: All 3 ended up working, just had to add the multiline flag to get it going - thanks both for your help

Comment: No, it is not quite possible, the first will work in .NET and JavaScript, and the version with `\K` will work in PCRE/Onigmo. Where are you using the regex?

Comment: I'm using mine in Python using the `regex` module, just chose the first one I picked out which is `(?<=^[^\S\r\n]*)` pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyPi `regex`, you can use

```py
import regex

text = r"""--hello
--goodbye
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) --date
  --comment with some indentation
    --another comment with some indentation"""

print( regex.findall(r'(?<=^[^\S\r\n]*)--.*', text, regex.M) )
# => ['--hello', '--goodbye', '--comment with some indentation', '--another comment with some indentation']
```

See this [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##fY@9CsJAEIT7e4oljXeSs7E1iJKUGoh/iFGJZjUHyW04F9Snjxe0tpph5itm2jdXZMddZ5qWHIPDO76EYHwxROCCINC6wromofWdqLy8UWTp7rzcLOZJJhWk2yQDmWaxl/ke4tk6UaB1WTAK8OZKTYOW4Wm4ggc1CMaWPijYkPVEzxSWuEIHf1k/RYjWGcvyu3J0821R19IN5HQSnQ6nfJW73B6HSuvRcBBC/yL8wQsFqus@).

Or, with the default Python `re`:

```py
import re
 
text = r"""--hello
--goodbye
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) --date
  --comment with some indentation
    --another comment with some indentation"""
 
print( re.findall(r'^[^\S\r\n]*(--.*)', text, re.M) )
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/8GiCy8).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=^[^\S\r\n]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with start of string/line and zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `^` - start of a string (here, a line, because `re.M` / `regex.M` option is used)
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than non-whitespace, CR and LF chars (any whitespace but carriage returns and line feed chars)
- `(--.*)` - Group 1: `--` and the rest of the line (`.*` matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible).